# Form submit not working Chrome/Safari but working in Firefox/IE

Tags: forms, google-chrome, submit

I've spent two hours searching for solutions here and I've seen a lot of similar complaints, but none of the suggestions have worked for me or I'm incapable of figuring out the solution.  The submit button on this form, https://landcruisersdirect.com/contact/, does not work in Chrome or Safari but does work in Firefox and IE.  I haven't updated any code on the site, this is how it was built in 2014.  It seems this only recently stopped working.  Any suggestions or contractors to hire who can fix this?

Comment: Hi, this website is for developers help only and others might flag this to be deleted. However, I work as developer and you can reach me on micseltene.dev@gmail.com.

Comment: Ok thanks, I sent you an email.